# Does a system of equations consisting of a linear equation and a quadratic equation have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

A system of equations consisting of a linear equation and a quadratic equation has infinitely many solutions.
Is the statement true?
Can the statement be true even sometimes?

Comment: Not in general, since, for example $x^2+y^2=-1$ has no solution.

Comment: The new title is greatly improved over the original. Try to keep titles informative.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Consider a line and a circle. The intersection can atmost be 2 points. Or a line and a parabola for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in the projective plane $\mathbf P^2(\mathbf C)$, the intersection of the corresponding algebraic varieties is in general a finite set, and consists of $2$ points, unless  the line is a component of the conic.

In greater dimensions, say in $\mathbf P^r(\mathbf C)$, you get an algebraic variety of dimension $\ge r-2$, hence it has an infinite number of points.